# AngularJS not refreshing view after model changed as result of an event

Tags: javascript, events, view, angularjs, model

I've prepared [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/X3iNGcIIcjUNWSnuFkAc) with a simplified scenario of an app that I'm coding where this is happening.

A little explanation of the scenario:

- There is a controller that loads into the $scope a list of transactions (objects of type Transaction)
- This controller listens to an event produced by the service that is responsible for persisting new or updated Transaction objects, and then reloads the model
- The view renders the transaction list with ng-repeat
- Every transaction can be updated (commited or rolled back) individually
- The AngularJS app has a run() block that creates a new Transaction object every 2 seconds, simulating that these transactions come from an external source (an $http request against a server, for example)

What you will see is that no reload of the view is done when the model is reassigned with a fresh list of objects after receiving the event that the service produces.

I've been pulling my hair off the last 48h with this. The most common cause for this kind of behaviour is to modify the model outside AngularJS and not calling $apply(), but (i think that) this is not the case.

Also tried to check $scope.$$phase and the calling manually $apply or $digest (even if this could be considered potentially bad) with no success at all.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Is there any other strategy that I could apply?

Comment: What's suppose to happen when you hit a "Manual refresh" button?

Comment: I suppose that you've figured it out already by your answer below... Anyway, this button forces a reload of the model (as it fails to do so when the event hits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` is also "outside of Angular" and I'm not sure if you tried using $apply there. If you wrap the `transactions.persist(t);` in app.js within `$rootScope.$apply()` you will see the list refreshing every two seconds. Changes produced by "COMMIT" and "ROLL BACK" buttons are also being displayed immediately.

[Working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KhHAafkibTk9UDhx2lPy?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is true that setInterval would be outside AngularJS. Didn't think of it when designing the scenario. In my real app, there is no setIntervals and I'll try to modify it to remove them and simulate the new objects in other way.

Comment: It turns out that you were right and you've given me the clue I needed. I had some other non-related intervals running and even if they didn't have anything to do with the processes that were experiencing this problem, as soon as I fixed their code wrapping it within a $rootScope.$apply() :)